# Espresso dripping but yield & pour time is right

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine

everything seems right with my Breville Barista Max+ machine… the dose is 9g, grind size 18 and the output is 30g in 30s (inc. 7s of pre-infusion) pressure seems ok etc for a single shot. Tamp at 30lb of pressure etc, calibrated.

The only thing is that doesn’t seem right is; when the pour starts, it’s a slow stream to begin but slows to a drip. Also the puck is very Wet, though I’ve seen a lot of posts saying not to worry about puckology.

Should I worry about the dripping? Shot tastes good, slightly watery perhaps under a good level of cremer?

Answer (score 1):

For a single, presumeably with a double spout, dripping is normal. You'll only get a continuous stream when you pull a double. 30g out is actually pretty much from 9g in, a normal espresso would be 18g out.